# SSIS inserts null values if XML has repeating child elements with the same name

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, msbi

SSIS inserts null values into DB if XML has repeating child elements with the same name.

Sample XML:

```
<Tests>
<TestId> 1 </TestId>
<TestName> Test 1 </TestName>
<TestId> 2 </TestId>
<TestName> Test 2 </TestName>
<TestLocation> Country </TestLocation>
</Tests>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What is the output you wish to gain? 
is it something like this:

```
ElementName      Value
TestId           1 
TestName         Test 1 
TestId           2 
TestName         Test 2 
TestLocation     Country
```

Or

```
TestId  TestName    TestLocation
 1      Test 2      Country 
 2      Test 1      NULL
```

See below an example using T-SQL to extract the data out of the XML

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (x XML) 
DECLARE @Out TABLE (ElementName varchar(100), [Value] varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(
'<Tests>
<TestId> 1 </TestId>
<TestName> Test 1 </TestName>
<TestId> 2 </TestId>
<TestName> Test 2 </TestName>
<TestLocation> Country </TestLocation>
</Tests>'
)
INSERT INTO @Out
SELECT q.t.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') ElementName,  
       q.t.value ('.', 'varchar(1000)') [Value]

 FROM @T
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes ('/Tests/*') q(t)

SELECT * 
FROM @Out


SELECT [TestId], [TestName], [TestLocation]
FROM 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ElementName ORDER BY ElementName) Id , ElementName , [Value]
FROM @Out
) T 
    PIVOT 
        (
        MIN([value]) FOR ElementName in ([TestId], [TestName], [TestLocation])
        ) pv
```

Comment: hkravitz - Thanks for your response, actually I'm using SSIS 'XML Source' component to extract data from XML. 
Finally, it is working after update of XSD file.
Thank you again for your assistance ;)